# Changing a label based on selected item of combobox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, ado.net, label

attempting to change text based on a combobox selection. C#, windows form, combobox loads on form load.
using an ADO entity data model to map the db, I have the tables added in. I have a combobox which loads the vendors, then a button that says get vendor. upon that I have 3 labels I want to display the vendor name, city and zip. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to make the label binded to the selected item from the combobox (the vendor selected) and make it change.

quick edit: I know the button code is wrong. but its where i'm at so I posted it. Thanks!

```
    PayablesEntities payablesSet = new PayablesEntities();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxVendor.DataSource = payablesSet.Vendors.ToList();
        comboBoxVendor.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBoxVendor.ValueMember = "VendorID";
    }

    private void buttonGetVendor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         label5.text = comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! needed a query to store that selected item's info, duh!

```
    private void buttonGetVendor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int vendorID = (int)comboBoxVendor.SelectedValue;
        var selectVendor =
                (from vendor in payablesSet.Vendors
                 where vendor.VendorID == vendorID
                 select vendor).First();
        label5.Text = selectVendor.Name;
        label6.Text = selectVendor.City;
        label7.Text = selectVendor.ZipCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.